# XSLT function document() using wildcard

Tags: xslt

Is there any possibility to use a wildcard for the `document()` function in XSLT like:

```
document("*.xml")
```

This is the same question: http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200108/msg00542.html

However this post is from 2001 so there might be any new techniques to solve this. Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to use a wildcard for the `document()` function

No, there aren't any such changes to the behaviour of the `document()` function.

However, XPath 2.0 (and that means available in XSLT 2.0) offers the standard function [**`collection()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection)

Its behavior is to some extent implementation dependent.

**Example** (based on Saxon 9):

This XPath expression:

```
collection('file:///c:/?select=report_*.xml')
```

selects the document nodes of every XML document that resides in `c:\` in a file with name starting with `report_` then having a 0 or more characters, then ending with `.xml`.

Comment: Saxon documentation of collection() function: [http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.xml](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.xml)

Comment: I don't understand this answer. But it works perfectly.

Comment: @habrewning, Glad this answer is useful to you. In order to learn more about the `fn:collection`, one could visit the link provided in the answer.