# How to programmatically iterate in XSLT across multiple files with similar name

Tags: xslt

A have following xmls:

data_0.xml
data_1.xml
data_3.xml
and so on...

And in xslt file I want to iterate through all files, so I tried for-each function.

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('data.xml')/*">
```

How to iterate on all of them? Add mask somehow? This surely won't work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('data_*.xml')/*">
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0, or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: If it was 2.0 would there be an easy solution?

Comment: Yes, in XSLT 2.0 you can use the **collection** function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595117/xslt-function-document-using-wildcard/8595589#8595589. In XSLT 1.0 you would probably need to pass in the a list of file names as parameters.

Comment: I changed <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"> to 2.0 and still collection function is unknown...

Comment: @tytan, if you want to use XSLT 2.0 then you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or AltovaXML.

Comment: Is the pattern for the file names really that simple? Do you know at the time of invocation what the max number is, or do you have something from an external language calling the XSLT (java,.net, python ANT, bash, etc.) that could pass in the list of file names or the max number as a parameter value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution in xslt 1.0:

I have four files in my filesystem:

**Doc1.xml:**

```
<p>Doc1</p>
```

**Doc2.xml:**

```
<p>Doc2</p>
```

**Doc3.xml:**

```
<p>Doc3</p>
```

**Doc4.xml:**

```
<p>Doc4</p>
```

and my **xslt** to get their output is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Root>
      <xsl:call-template name="getDocuments"/>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="getDocuments">
  <xsl:param name="fileStartWith" select="'Doc'"/>
  <xsl:param name="endCounter">4</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="startCounter">1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$endCounter > 0">
      <xsl:variable name="fileName"><xsl:value-of select="concat($fileStartWith,$startCounter,'.xml')"/></xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each select="document($fileName)/*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:call-template name="getDocuments">
        <xsl:with-param name="startCounter" select="$startCounter + 1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="fileStartWith" select="$fileStartWith"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="endCounter" select="$endCounter - 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

generated **output** is:

```
<Root>
<p>Doc1</p>
<p>Doc2</p>
<p>Doc3</p>
<p>Doc4</p>
</Root>
```

Please make sure that xslt and xml is on the same path otherwise you need to change the content of document function.

Comment: Can I replace hardcoded value of endCounter with last file detection? Maybe IF ending when root tag is empty?

Comment: Yes you can change, it is just a param value to track how many loops need to run only. I have checked your concern for empty root element, but is is working fine.