# merge multiple XML files using STAX parser

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, stax

I have multiple XML files.all nodes are similar. Please provide an example how to merge XML files using  STAX Parser and apply a stylesheet on it.

Comment: How is this question related to [another question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512015/merge-two-or-more-xml-files-and-display-as-html-using-xslt)?

Comment: i tried to achieve this requirement by style sheet.but later decided to use STAX parser because every time file names will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply XSLT to several XML documents then (with pure XSLT, I don't know about Stax) you can simply use the `document` function (XSLT 1.0 and 2.0) or the `collection` function (with XSLT 2.0) e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file1.xml')/* | document('file2.xml')/* | document('file3.xml')/*"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>
```

then add templates matching the element names in the documents you want process.

Comment: This works for fixed file names. but my use case is different, files names will change based on the job we are going to run.

Comment: If you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 then you should be able to use the `collection` function to load files from a directory or folder. Let us know whether that is an option for you.

Comment: Thanks. It works for me .Please gimme complete example ,if possible.

Comment: I'm performing a very similar action from what it sounds like the asker is doing... Curious as to how to approach this.