# How to parse the XML using Stax parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I want to parse the XML Using STAX Parser.

1) **Load The XML Content and print it down on the console.**

**Expected Output:**

```
    ObjectID = OR:wt.part.WTPart:117313:425251666-1466176866678-1329564238-1-0-0-127@tibco.ptc.com

Class = com.ptc.windchill.esi.Part

LastChangedBy = LastChangedBy
```

and so on whatever the tag present in XML.

I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580137/merge-multiple-xml-files-using-stax-parser) but it did not help me,
My Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wc:COLLECTION xmlns:wc="http://www.ptc.com/infoengine/1.0">
<Release NAME="Release" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</Release>
<DeletedECN NAME="DeletedECN" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedECN>
<AddedECN NAME="AddedECN" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedECN>
<ChangedECN NAME="ChangedECN" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedECN>
<UnchangedECN NAME="UnchangedECN" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedECN>
<DeletedParts NAME="DeletedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedParts>
<AddedParts NAME="AddedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
<Part>
    <ObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPart:117313:425251666-1466176866678-1329564238-1-0-0-127@tibco.ptc.com</ObjectID>
    <Class>com.ptc.windchill.esi.Part</Class>
    <LastChangedBy>Administrator</LastChangedBy>
    <Number>0000000032</Number>
    <StartEffectivity></StartEffectivity>
    <EndEffectivity></EndEffectivity>
    <StartSerialNumberEffectivity></StartSerialNumberEffectivity>
    <EndSerialNumberEffectivity></EndSerialNumberEffectivity>
    <StartLotNumberEffectivity></StartLotNumberEffectivity>
    <EndLotNumberEffectivity></EndLotNumberEffectivity>
    <SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber></SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber>
    <LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber></LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber>
    <DefaultUnit>ea</DefaultUnit>
    <Name>test16</Name>
    <PartType>separable</PartType>
    <Source>make</Source>
    <State>INWORK</State>
    <IsPhantom>false</IsPhantom>
    <Version>A</Version>
    <Iteration>1</Iteration>
    <PreviousVersion></PreviousVersion>
    <IsConfigurable>standard</IsConfigurable>
    <IsCollapsible>false</IsCollapsible>
    <TargetID>1</TargetID>
</Part>
</AddedParts>
<ChangedParts NAME="ChangedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedParts>
<UnchangedParts NAME="UnchangedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedParts>
<DeletedAlternateLinks NAME="DeletedAlternateLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedAlternateLinks>
<AddedAlternateLinks NAME="AddedAlternateLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedAlternateLinks>
<DeletedDocuments NAME="DeletedDocuments" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedDocuments>
<AddedDocuments NAME="AddedDocuments" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedDocuments>
<ChangedDocuments NAME="ChangedDocuments" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedDocuments>
<UnchangedDocuments NAME="UnchangedDocuments" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedDocuments>
<DeletedDocumentLinks NAME="DeletedDocumentLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedDocumentLinks>
<AddedDocumentLinks NAME="AddedDocumentLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedDocumentLinks>
<ChangedDocumentLinks NAME="ChangedDocumentLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedDocumentLinks>
<UnchangedDocumentLinks NAME="UnchangedDocumentLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedDocumentLinks>
<DeletedBOMs NAME="DeletedBOMs" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedBOMs>
<AddedBOMs NAME="AddedBOMs" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedBOMs>
<ChangedBOMs NAME="ChangedBOMs" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedBOMs>
<UnchangedBOMs NAME="UnchangedBOMs" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedBOMs>
<DeletedBOMComponents NAME="DeletedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedBOMComponents>
<AddedBOMComponents NAME="AddedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedBOMComponents>
<ChangedBOMComponents NAME="ChangedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedBOMComponents>
<UnchangedBOMComponents NAME="UnchangedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedBOMComponents>
<DeletedSubstitutes NAME="DeletedSubstitutes" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedSubstitutes>
<AddedSubstitutes NAME="AddedSubstitutes" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedSubstitutes>
<DeletedReferenceDesignators NAME="DeletedReferenceDesignators" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedReferenceDesignators>
<AddedReferenceDesignators NAME="AddedReferenceDesignators" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedReferenceDesignators>
<DeletedProcessMaterials NAME="DeletedProcessMaterials" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedProcessMaterials>
<AddedProcessMaterials NAME="AddedProcessMaterials" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedProcessMaterials>
<ChangedProcessMaterials NAME="ChangedProcessMaterials" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedProcessMaterials>
<UnchangedProcessMaterials NAME="UnchangedProcessMaterials" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedProcessMaterials>
<DeletedToolings NAME="DeletedToolings" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedToolings>
<AddedToolings NAME="AddedToolings" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedToolings>
<ChangedToolings NAME="ChangedToolings" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedToolings>
<UnchangedToolings NAME="UnchangedToolings" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedToolings>
<DeletedProcessPlans NAME="DeletedProcessPlans" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedProcessPlans>
<AddedProcessPlans NAME="AddedProcessPlans" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedProcessPlans>
<ChangedProcessPlans NAME="ChangedProcessPlans" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedProcessPlans>
<UnchangedProcessPlans NAME="UnchangedProcessPlans" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedProcessPlans>
<DeletedOperations NAME="DeletedOperations" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOperations>
<AddedOperations NAME="AddedOperations" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOperations>
<ChangedOperations NAME="ChangedOperations" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOperations>
<UnchangedOperations NAME="UnchangedOperations" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOperations>
<DeletedOperationUsageLinks NAME="DeletedOperationUsageLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOperationUsageLinks>
<AddedOperationUsageLinks NAME="AddedOperationUsageLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOperationUsageLinks>
<ChangedOperationUsageLinks NAME="ChangedOperationUsageLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOperationUsageLinks>
<UnchangedOperationUsageLinks NAME="UnchangedOperationUsageLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOperationUsageLinks>
<DeletedProcessPlanPartLinks NAME="DeletedProcessPlanPartLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedProcessPlanPartLinks>
<AddedProcessPlanPartLinks NAME="AddedProcessPlanPartLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedProcessPlanPartLinks>
<ChangedProcessPlanPartLinks NAME="ChangedProcessPlanPartLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedProcessPlanPartLinks>
<UnchangedProcessPlanPartLinks NAME="UnchangedProcessPlanPartLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedProcessPlanPartLinks>
<DeletedSequences NAME="DeletedSequences" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedSequences>
<AddedSequences NAME="AddedSequences" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedSequences>
<ChangedSequences NAME="ChangedSequences" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedSequences>
<UnchangedSequences NAME="UnchangedSequences" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedSequences>
<DeletedOprConsumableResourceLinks NAME="DeletedOprConsumableResourceLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOprConsumableResourceLinks>
<AddedOprConsumableResourceLinks NAME="AddedOprConsumableResourceLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOprConsumableResourceLinks>
<ChangedOprConsumableResourceLinks NAME="ChangedOprConsumableResourceLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOprConsumableResourceLinks>
<UnchangedOprConsumableResourceLinks NAME="UnchangedOprConsumableResourceLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOprConsumableResourceLinks>
<DeletedOprWorkCenterLinks NAME="DeletedOprWorkCenterLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOprWorkCenterLinks>
<AddedOprWorkCenterLinks NAME="AddedOprWorkCenterLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOprWorkCenterLinks>
<ChangedOprWorkCenterLinks NAME="ChangedOprWorkCenterLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOprWorkCenterLinks>
<UnchangedOprWorkCenterLinks NAME="UnchangedOprWorkCenterLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOprWorkCenterLinks>
<DeletedOprBomAllocatedParts NAME="DeletedOprBomAllocatedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOprBomAllocatedParts>
<AddedOprBomAllocatedParts NAME="AddedOprBomAllocatedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOprBomAllocatedParts>
<ChangedOprBomAllocatedParts NAME="ChangedOprBomAllocatedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOprBomAllocatedParts>
<UnchangedOprBomAllocatedParts NAME="UnchangedOprBomAllocatedParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOprBomAllocatedParts>
<DeletedOprOperatedOnParts NAME="DeletedOprOperatedOnParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOprOperatedOnParts>
<AddedOprOperatedOnParts NAME="AddedOprOperatedOnParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOprOperatedOnParts>
<ChangedOprOperatedOnParts NAME="ChangedOprOperatedOnParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOprOperatedOnParts>
<UnchangedOprOperatedOnParts NAME="UnchangedOprOperatedOnParts" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOprOperatedOnParts>
<DeletedStandardProcedureLinks NAME="DeletedStandardProcedureLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedStandardProcedureLinks>
<AddedStandardProcedureLinks NAME="AddedStandardProcedureLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedStandardProcedureLinks>
<ChangedStandardProcedureLinks NAME="ChangedStandardProcedureLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedStandardProcedureLinks>
<UnchangedStandardProcedureLinks NAME="UnchangedStandardProcedureLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedStandardProcedureLinks>
<DeletedSkills NAME="DeletedSkills" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedSkills>
<AddedSkills NAME="AddedSkills" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedSkills>
<ChangedSkills NAME="ChangedSkills" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedSkills>
<UnchangedSkills NAME="UnchangedSkills" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedSkills>
<DeletedPlants NAME="DeletedPlants" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedPlants>
<AddedPlants NAME="AddedPlants" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedPlants>
<ChangedPlants NAME="ChangedPlants" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedPlants>
<UnchangedPlants NAME="UnchangedPlants" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedPlants>
<DeletedResourceGroups NAME="DeletedResourceGroups" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedResourceGroups>
<AddedResourceGroups NAME="AddedResourceGroups" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedResourceGroups>
<ChangedResourceGroups NAME="ChangedResourceGroups" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedResourceGroups>
<UnchangedResourceGroups NAME="UnchangedResourceGroups" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedResourceGroups>
<DeletedWorkCenters NAME="DeletedWorkCenters" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedWorkCenters>
<AddedWorkCenters NAME="AddedWorkCenters" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedWorkCenters>
<ChangedWorkCenters NAME="ChangedWorkCenters" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedWorkCenters>
<UnchangedWorkCenters NAME="UnchangedWorkCenters" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedWorkCenters>
<DeletedPlantAssignmentLinks NAME="DeletedPlantAssignmentLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedPlantAssignmentLinks>
<AddedPlantAssignmentLinks NAME="AddedPlantAssignmentLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedPlantAssignmentLinks>
<ChangedPlantAssignmentLinks NAME="ChangedPlantAssignmentLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedPlantAssignmentLinks>
<UnchangedPlantAssignmentLinks NAME="UnchangedPlantAssignmentLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedPlantAssignmentLinks>
<DeletedResourceUsageLinks NAME="DeletedResourceUsageLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedResourceUsageLinks>
<AddedResourceUsageLinks NAME="AddedResourceUsageLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedResourceUsageLinks>
<ChangedResourceUsageLinks NAME="ChangedResourceUsageLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedResourceUsageLinks>
<UnchangedResourceUsageLinks NAME="UnchangedResourceUsageLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedResourceUsageLinks>
<CurrentAUMs NAME="CurrentAUMs" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</CurrentAUMs>
<AddedEPMRepresentations NAME="AddedEPMRepresentations" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedEPMRepresentations>
<DeletedControlCharacteristics NAME="DeletedControlCharacteristics" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedControlCharacteristics>
<AddedControlCharacteristics NAME="AddedControlCharacteristics" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedControlCharacteristics>
<ChangedControlCharacteristics NAME="ChangedControlCharacteristics" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedControlCharacteristics>
<UnchangedControlCharacteristics NAME="UnchangedControlCharacteristics" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedControlCharacteristics>
<ModelItems NAME="ModelItems" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ModelItems>
<DeletedQualityLinks NAME="DeletedQualityLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedQualityLinks>
<AddedQualityLinks NAME="AddedQualityLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedQualityLinks>
<ChangedQualityLinks NAME="ChangedQualityLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedQualityLinks>
<UnchangedQualityLinks NAME="UnchangedQualityLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedQualityLinks>
<DeletedOptionSets NAME="DeletedOptionSets" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOptionSets>
<AddedOptionSets NAME="AddedOptionSets" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOptionSets>
<ChangedOptionSets NAME="ChangedOptionSets" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOptionSets>
<UnchangedOptionSets NAME="UnchangedOptionSets" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOptionSets>
<DeletedOptions NAME="DeletedOptions" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOptions>
<AddedOptions NAME="AddedOptions" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOptions>
<ChangedOptions NAME="ChangedOptions" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOptions>
<UnchangedOptions NAME="UnchangedOptions" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOptions>
<DeletedChoices NAME="DeletedChoices" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedChoices>
<AddedChoices NAME="AddedChoices" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedChoices>
<ChangedChoices NAME="ChangedChoices" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedChoices>
<UnchangedChoices NAME="UnchangedChoices" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedChoices>
<DeletedOptionSetOptionLinks NAME="DeletedOptionSetOptionLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOptionSetOptionLinks>
<AddedOptionSetOptionLinks NAME="AddedOptionSetOptionLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOptionSetOptionLinks>
<DeletedOptionSetMemberLinks NAME="DeletedOptionSetMemberLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOptionSetMemberLinks>
<AddedOptionSetMemberLinks NAME="AddedOptionSetMemberLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOptionSetMemberLinks>
<ChangedOptionSetMemberLinks NAME="ChangedOptionSetMemberLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOptionSetMemberLinks>
<UnchangedOptionSetMemberLinks NAME="UnchangedOptionSetMemberLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOptionSetMemberLinks>
<DeletedAssociatedOptionSetLinks NAME="DeletedAssociatedOptionSetLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedAssociatedOptionSetLinks>
<AddedAssociatedOptionSetLinks NAME="AddedAssociatedOptionSetLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedAssociatedOptionSetLinks>
<DeletedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks NAME="DeletedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks>
<AddedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks NAME="AddedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks>
<ChangedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks NAME="ChangedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks>
<UnchangedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks NAME="UnchangedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedChoiceMappableChoiceLinks>
<DeletedOptionSetRuleLinks NAME="DeletedOptionSetRuleLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedOptionSetRuleLinks>
<AddedOptionSetRuleLinks NAME="AddedOptionSetRuleLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedOptionSetRuleLinks>
<ChangedOptionSetRuleLinks NAME="ChangedOptionSetRuleLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedOptionSetRuleLinks>
<UnchangedOptionSetRuleLinks NAME="UnchangedOptionSetRuleLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedOptionSetRuleLinks>
<DeletedRules NAME="DeletedRules" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedRules>
<AddedRules NAME="AddedRules" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedRules>
<ChangedRules NAME="ChangedRules" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedRules>
<UnchangedRules NAME="UnchangedRules" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedRules>
<DeletedRuleMemberLinks NAME="DeletedRuleMemberLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedRuleMemberLinks>
<AddedRuleMemberLinks NAME="AddedRuleMemberLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedRuleMemberLinks>
<ChangedRuleMemberLinks NAME="ChangedRuleMemberLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedRuleMemberLinks>
<UnchangedRuleMemberLinks NAME="UnchangedRuleMemberLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedRuleMemberLinks>
<DeletedRuleMemberActionLinks NAME="DeletedRuleMemberActionLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedRuleMemberActionLinks>
<AddedRuleMemberActionLinks NAME="AddedRuleMemberActionLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedRuleMemberActionLinks>
<ChangedRuleMemberActionLinks NAME="ChangedRuleMemberActionLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedRuleMemberActionLinks>
<UnchangedRuleMemberActionLinks NAME="UnchangedRuleMemberActionLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedRuleMemberActionLinks>
<DeletedPlantLocalizationLinks NAME="DeletedPlantLocalizationLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedPlantLocalizationLinks>
<AddedPlantLocalizationLinks NAME="AddedPlantLocalizationLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedPlantLocalizationLinks>
<ChangedPlantLocalizationLinks NAME="ChangedPlantLocalizationLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedPlantLocalizationLinks>
<UnchangedPlantLocalizationLinks NAME="UnchangedPlantLocalizationLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedPlantLocalizationLinks>
<DeletedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks NAME="DeletedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</DeletedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks>
<AddedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks NAME="AddedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</AddedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks>
<ChangedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks NAME="ChangedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</ChangedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks>
<UnchangedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks NAME="UnchangedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
</UnchangedProcessPlanLocalizationLinks>
</wc:COLLECTION>
```

I Do something like :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;


public class StaxParserDemo 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws XMLStreamException 
    {
        List<WcCOLLECTION> empList = null;
        WcCOLLECTION currEmp = null;
        String tagContent = null;
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader reader = 
            factory.createXMLStreamReader(
            ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("c:\\file.xml"));

        while(reader.hasNext()){
          int event = reader.next();

          switch(event){
            case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT: 
              if ("Part".equals(reader.getLocalName())){
                currEmp = new WcCOLLECTION();
                currEmp.ObjectID = reader.getAttributeValue(0);
              }
              if("Part".equals(reader.getLocalName())){
                empList = new ArrayList<>();
              }
              break;

            case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
              tagContent = reader.getText().trim();
              break;

            case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
              switch(reader.getLocalName()){
                case "Part":
                  empList.add(currEmp);
                  break;
                case "ObjectID":
                  currEmp.ObjectID = tagContent;
                  break;
                case "Class":
                  currEmp.Class = tagContent;
                  break;
                case "LastChangedBy":
                  currEmp.LastChangedBy = tagContent;
                  break;
                case "StartEffectivity":
                      currEmp.StartEffectivity = tagContent;
                      break;
              }
              break;

            case XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT:
              empList = new ArrayList<>();
              break;
          }

        }

        //Print the employee list populated from XML
        for ( WcCOLLECTION emp : empList){
          System.out.println(emp);
        }

      }
    }

    class WcCOLLECTION
    {
        String ObjectID;
        String Class;
        String LastChangedBy;
        String Number;
        String StartEffectivity;
        String EndEffectivity;
        String StartSerialNumberEffectivity;
        String EndSerialNumberEffectivity;
        String StartLotNumberEffectivity;
        String EndLotNumberEffectivity;
        String SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber;
        String LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber;
        String DefaultUnit;
        String Name;
        String PartType;
        String Source;
        String State;
        String IsPhantom;
        String Version;
        String Iteration;
        String PreviousVersion;
        String IsConfigurable;
        String IsCollapsible;
        String TargetID;

      @Override
      public String toString()
      {
        //return Class+" "+LastChangedBy+"("+ObjectID+") "+StartEffectivity+" "+EndEffectivity+" "+StartSerialNumberEffectivity+" "+EndSerialNumberEffectivity+" "+SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber+" "+LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber+" "+DefaultUnit+" "+Name+" "+PartType+" "+Source+" "+State+" "+IsPhantom+" "+State+" "+Version+" "+Iteration+" "+PreviousVersion+" "+IsConfigurable+" "+IsCollapsible+" "+TargetID;

          return Class+" "+LastChangedBy+"("+ObjectID+") "+StartEffectivity;
      }

}
```

Comment: if you would like to take some node please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351826/stax-get-xml-node-as-string . if you would like to hve beautiful output from your current application just correct WcCOLLECTION.toString() method and case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT.

Comment: is stax parsing a requirement? Have you tried to do it with DOM?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author There is requirement of either STAX,SAX, or JAXB but no Dom

Comment: No DOM because the file is very big so as to cause out of memory exception? how big is your XML? Also why is jaxb allowed, as it holds an in memory model like DOM as well?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author My File Is Dynamic in nature. The Xml file Contain the Windhill Part Information which is retrieve from ERP. It is ok if i go for JAXB or SAX and STAX But no Dom Because it causes the out of memeory exception

Answer (score 1):

I write some java code it parse the XML Using STAX Parser, It works fine :

```
public class ErpStAXParser 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        // all the required attributes from the xml file which will need to print 
          boolean ObjectID = false;
          boolean Class = false;
          boolean LastChangedBy = false;
          boolean Number = false;
          boolean StartEffectivity = false;
          boolean EndEffectivity = false;
          boolean StartSerialNumberEffectivity = false;
          boolean EndSerialNumberEffectivity = false;
          boolean StartLotNumberEffectivity = false;
          boolean EndLotNumberEffectivity = false;
          boolean SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber = false;
          boolean LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber = false;
          boolean DefaultUnit = false;
          boolean Name = false;
          boolean PartType = false;
          boolean Source = false;
          boolean State = false;
          boolean IsPhantom = false;
          boolean Version = false;
          boolean Iteration = false;
          boolean PreviousVersion = false;
          boolean IsConfigurable = false;
          boolean IsCollapsible = false;
          boolean TargetID = false;

          try 
          {
                 XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
                 XMLEventReader eventReader =
                 factory.createXMLEventReader(
                    new FileReader("c:\\staxTestFile.xml"));
                 while(eventReader.hasNext())
                 {
                       XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
                       switch(event.getEventType())
                       {
                          case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:
                              StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
                                 String qName = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();
                                 if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Part")) 
                                 {
                                        System.out.println("Start Element : Part");
                                        Iterator<Attribute> attributes = startElement.getAttributes();

                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ObjectID")) 
                                 {
                                     ObjectID = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Class")) 
                                 {
                                     Class = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LastChangedBy")) 
                                 {
                                     LastChangedBy = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Number")) 
                                 {
                                     Number = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("StartEffectivity")) 
                                 {
                                     StartEffectivity = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("EndSerialNumberEffectivity")) 
                                 {
                                     EndSerialNumberEffectivity = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("StartSerialNumberEffectivity")) 
                                 {
                                     StartSerialNumberEffectivity = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("EndSerialNumberEffectivity")) 
                                 {
                                     EndSerialNumberEffectivity = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("StartLotNumberEffectivity")) 
                                 {
                                     StartLotNumberEffectivity = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("EndLotNumberEffectivity")) 
                                 {
                                     EndLotNumberEffectivity = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber")) 
                                 {
                                     SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber")) 
                                 {
                                     LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("DefaultUnit")) 
                                 {
                                     DefaultUnit = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name")) 
                                 {
                                     Name = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("PartType")) 
                                 {
                                     PartType = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Source")) 
                                 {
                                     Source = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("State")) 
                                 {
                                     State = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("IsPhantom")) 
                                 {
                                     IsPhantom = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Version")) 
                                 {
                                     Version = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Iteration")) 
                                 {
                                     Iteration = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("PreviousVersion")) 
                                 {
                                     PreviousVersion = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("IsConfigurable")) 
                                 {
                                     IsConfigurable = true;
                                 } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("IsCollapsible")) 
                                 {
                                     IsCollapsible = true;
                                 }
                                 else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("TargetID")) 
                                 {
                                     TargetID = true;
                                 }
                                 break;

                          case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS:
                          Characters characters = event.asCharacters();

                          if(ObjectID){
                                    System.out.println("ObjectID: " 
                                    + characters.getData());
                                    ObjectID = false;
                                 }
                                 if(Class){
                                    System.out.println("Class: " 
                                    + characters.getData());
                                    Class = false;
                                 }
                                 if(LastChangedBy){
                                    System.out.println("LastChangedBy " 
                                    + characters.getData());
                                    LastChangedBy = false;
                                 }
                                 if(Number){
                                    System.out.println("Number: " 
                                    + characters.getData());
                                    Number = false;
                                 }
                                 if(StartEffectivity){
                                        System.out.println("StartEffectivity: " 
                                        + characters.getData());
                                        StartEffectivity = false;
                                     }
                                     if(EndEffectivity){
                                        System.out.println("EndEffectivity " 
                                        + characters.getData());
                                        EndEffectivity = false;
                                     }
                                     if(StartSerialNumberEffectivity){
                                        System.out.println("StartSerialNumberEffectivity " 
                                        + characters.getData());
                                        StartSerialNumberEffectivity = false;
                                     }
                                     if(EndSerialNumberEffectivity){
                                        System.out.println("EndSerialNumberEffectivity: " 
                                        + characters.getData());
                                        EndSerialNumberEffectivity = false;
                                     }
                                     if(StartLotNumberEffectivity){
                                            System.out.println("StartLotNumberEffectivity" 
                                            + characters.getData());
                                            StartLotNumberEffectivity = false;
                                         }
                                         if(EndLotNumberEffectivity){
                                            System.out.println("EndLotNumberEffectivity: " 
                                            + characters.getData());
                                            EndLotNumberEffectivity = false;
                                         }
                                         if(SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber){
                                            System.out.println("SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber " 
                                            + characters.getData());
                                            SerialNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber = false;
                                         }
                                         if(LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber){
                                            System.out.println("LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber: " 
                                            + characters.getData());
                                            LotNumberEffectivityCxtPartNumber = false;
                                         }
                                         if(DefaultUnit){
                                                System.out.println("DefaultUnit: " 
                                                + characters.getData());
                                                DefaultUnit = false;
                                             }
                                             if(Name){
                                                System.out.println("Name: " 
                                                + characters.getData());
                                                Name = false;
                                             }
                                             if(PartType){
                                                System.out.println("PartType: " 
                                                + characters.getData());
                                                PartType = false;
                                             }
                                             if(Source){
                                                System.out.println("Source: " 
                                                + characters.getData());
                                                Source = false;
                                             }
                                             if(State){
                                                    System.out.println("State: " 
                                                    + characters.getData());
                                                    State = false;
                                                 }
                                                 if(IsPhantom){
                                                    System.out.println("IsPhantom: " 
                                                    + characters.getData());
                                                    IsPhantom = false;
                                                 }
                                                 if(Version){
                                                    System.out.println("Version: " 
                                                    + characters.getData());
                                                    Version = false;
                                                 }
                                                 if(Iteration){
                                                    System.out.println("Iteration: " 
                                                    + characters.getData());
                                                    Iteration = false;
                                                 }
                                                 if(PreviousVersion){
                                                        System.out.println("PreviousVersion: " 
                                                        + characters.getData());
                                                        PreviousVersion = false;
                                                     }
                                                     if(IsConfigurable){
                                                        System.out.println("IsConfigurable: " 
                                                        + characters.getData());
                                                        IsConfigurable = false;
                                                     }
                                                     if(IsCollapsible){
                                                        System.out.println("IsCollapsible: " 
                                                        + characters.getData());
                                                        IsCollapsible = false;
                                                     }
                                                     if(TargetID){
                                                        System.out.println("TargetID: " 
                                                        + characters.getData());
                                                        TargetID = false;
                                                     }
                                                     break;
                          case  XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
                                 EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
                                 if(endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equalsIgnoreCase("Part")){
                                        System.out.println("End Element : Part");
                                        System.out.println();
                                     }
                                     break;
                       }//switch



          }//while
          }//try
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }




}//main
}//class
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample based on XPath and VTD-XML. It will dump all elements and their contents under the part node. Although it loads everything in memory, it will not blow up like DOM.

```
import com.ximpleware.*;

public class dumpKeyValue {

    public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot();
        ap.selectXPath("//part/*[text()]");
        if (!vg.parseFile("d:\\xml\\soap.xml", false)){
            System.out.println("invalid xml");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        ap.bind(vn);
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            System.out.println(" "+vn.toRawString(i)+" = "+vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to buy any licences for it?